# Converter JSON para Array Enviar via Curl

Tags: php, json, array, libcurl

```
$jsonData = array("amount"=>500,"payload"=>{"duplicateTedAgreement"=>false,"favoriteIdTo"=>"x"});
$ch = curl_init( $url );
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
```

Erro que retorna `Parse error : syntax error, unexpected`

Comment: Não é possível fazer isso `array("payload" => {"duplicateTedAgreement" => false, "favoriteIdTo" => "x"}});`

Comment: você sabe como devo fazer ? ja tentei desta forma $jsonData = array("amount"=>500,"payload"=>"duplicateTedAgreement"=>false,"favoriteIdTo"=>"x"); porem da erro tbm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu código existe um problema, está tentando definir um valor em objeto para uma chave dentro do array diretamente, esse é o motivo do seu erro, nessa linha:

```
$jsonData = array("amount" => 500, "payload" => {"duplicateTedAgreement" => false, "favoriteIdTo" => "x" });
```

Está tentando atribuir à uma posição do array um objeto `"payload" => {}`.

Caso seja necessário o uso desse objeto você pode fazer dessa forma, instânciando da classe interna `stdClass`, ou seja, na pratica você define como um array, mas força ele ser convertido em um objeto, com `(object)`:

```
$jsonData = array("amount" => 500, "payload" => (object)["duplicateTedAgreement" => false, "favoriteIdTo" => "x"]);

/* RESULTADO */
array(2) {
  ["amount"]=>
  int(500)
  ["payload"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
    ["duplicateTedAgreement"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["favoriteIdTo"]=>
    string(1) "x"
  }
}
```

No caso da questão, como já é feito a conversão para `json`, não é necessário o uso do `(object)`, basta definir como um array, que o próprio `json_encode` já faz essa conversão, ficando dessa forma:

```
$jsonData = array("amount" => 500, "payload" => ["duplicateTedAgreement" => false, "favoriteIdTo" => "x"]);
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData)

/* RESULTADO */
{
    "amount": 500,
    "payload": {
        "duplicateTedAgreement": false,
        "favoriteIdTo": "x"
    }
}
```

> Créditos ao [Augusto Vasques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques) pelo comentário, não havia notado o `json_encode`.

Comment: Acho que não precisa do `(object)` antes do array: https://repl.it/repls/BrokenHeftyBrain

Comment: @AugustoVasques, verdade, como é convertido para `json`, o próprio já faz a conversão, não reparei no `json_encode`, obrigado pela sugestão.